# adding my posts (author posts) in menu

Tags: posts, archives, author

I want to add "my posts" to main menu. By clicking on this, each logged-in user will see his/her own posts.

I don't know how the link structure should be to add on the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url() . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID ); ?>" >My Posts</a>
```